# is it possible to control android firewall

Tags: android

i want control over internet activity something like white-list in parent control , So that any browser or others app just can browse white-list address not more
  is it possible؟  , can do that without rooting device؟

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible؟ , can do that without rooting device؟

No, you can not do this on unrooted device. On rooted device, you need to simply add rules in the `/etc/hosts` file for that.

For example, if you want to block facebook then write this rule

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "0.0.0.0 http://facebook.com" >> /etc/hosts'
```

Comment: thanks , but there is some app do that(parent control) without rooting

Comment: @Himidrez I don't think that app work on android google chrome. Does it ?